# rails-latex can't find pdflatex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, latex

I'm using Rails 4.1.4 with `rails-latex` gem to generate PDFs, but I got this error when viewing the PDF:

```
pdflatex failed: See /home/sarunint/dockey/tmp/rails-latex/3639-548202856440663759/input.log for details
```

And this is the content of the log file:

```
No such file or directory - pdflatex:
/home/sarunint/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rails-latex-1.0.12/lib/rails-latex/latex_to_pdf.rb:34:in `exec'
/home/sarunint/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rails-latex-1.0.12/lib/rails-latex/latex_to_pdf.rb:34:in `block in generate_pdf'
/home/sarunint/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rails-latex-1.0.12/lib/rails-latex/latex_to_pdf.rb:27:in `fork'
/home/sarunint/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rails-latex-1.0.12/lib/rails-latex/latex_to_pdf.rb:27:in `generate_pdf'
/home/sarunint/dockey/app/views/static_pages/home.pdf.erbtex:5:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_pdf_erbtex___3893833075752892539_70272278165640'
/home/sarunint/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
/home/sarunint/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
/home/sarunint/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
/home/sarunint/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
...much more...
```

I'm pretty sure that the latex is installed on my system.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Does the command `which pdflatex` return a location, or do you get a message like; `pdflatex: Command not found.`?

Comment: I got `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux` is either in your `$PATH`, or in whatever setting `rails-latex` uses to detect where to find programs.

Comment: OK, this path is in _my_ PATH but not in _www-data_'s path. Thanks a lot, took me almost 1 month to figure this out !

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix and how to add path

Comment: @ManishaOdedara The PATH can be set in a system wide configuration file, or in the configuration file of the user's shell.